# Angular Bootstrap row info same in modal when opening

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a simple dashboard-type application. I'd like there to be an edit button on every table row, when clicked, a modal with a form with filled rows should pop up.

However, when I click on some row, then every other "Edit" click after that produces a modal with the same data (the child component inside doesn't change). How could I refresh the modal every time it opens?

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit pet</h5>
          <button type="disposeBtn" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <app-editpet *ngIf="petToUpdate" [petInput]="petToUpdate"></app-editpet>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button that opens the modal for every row.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="edit(pet)">Edit pet</a>
```

My Typescript for the component.

```
declare var bootstrap: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mainview',
  templateUrl: './mainview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mainview.component.css']
})



export class MainviewComponent implements OnInit {
  pets: Pet[] = [];
  data: Pet[] = [];

  petToUpdate: Pet;

  timerSubscription: Subscription;

  interval: any;

  

  formModal: any;
  
  
  constructor(public petService: PetService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshData();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.refreshData();
    }, 1000);

    this.formModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"));

  }

  closeModal(){
    this.formModal.hide();
  }

 
  refreshData(){
    this.petService.getPets().subscribe((response => {
      this.pets = response;
      this.data = response;
    }));
  }



  reverseArray(){
    this.pets = this.data.reverse();
  }

  
  edit(pet: Pet){
    this.petToUpdate = pet;
    console.log(this.petToUpdate)
    this.formModal.show();
  }

  
}
```

I have tried dismissing the modal, which produces js not found errors, other than that I have no clue how to approach the problem. I get the problems core, the same modal instance is opened every time, however I can't find a workaround to it. All the materials are so dispersed. I'm quite lost.